my PyTorch machine learning program for regression is not learning
I am working on to create a machine learning project with PyTorch, and I realize my model does not seem to learn - it always outputs a flat line with little changes, and the loss hardly reduces. In order to spot the issue, I reduced my program to another minimum program (the program in question), yet the problem remains.
In this reduced program, I aim to make a model to approach to the shape of y=x^2. I copied and pasted my model class ANN from my original bigger project, which has 6 features. For simplicity, I set first 5 features to 0 and the last one to be the actual x (evenly separated numbers on interval from -2 to 2), and based on x generate corresponding y values by my generate_targets().
from torch import tensor, float32
from torch import nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ANN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_num: int):
        super(ANN,self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(feature_num, 300),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(300, 200),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(200, 150),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(150, 50),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(50, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        predictions = self.layers(x)
        return predictions


class TestDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, sample_num):
        self.sample_num = sample_num
        self.func_max = 2
        self.func_min = -2
        self.unit = (self.func_max - self.func_min) / self.sample_num
        self.targets = generate_targets(self.sample_num)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.func_min + index * self.unit
        return tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, x], dtype=float32), self.targets[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.sample_num


# Generate the list of y
def generate_targets(count):
    func_max = 2
    func_min = -2
    unit = (func_max - func_min)/count
    target_list = []
    for i in range(count):
        x = func_min + unit*i
        y = x ** 2
        target_list.append(y)
    return target_list


# The main program
def start_train():
    sample_num = 500
    train_data = TestDataset(sample_num)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

    model = ANN(6)
    model.train()
    mae_loss = nn.L1Loss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    loss_list = []

    for i in range(sample_num):
        train_feature, train_target = next(iter(train_dataloader))
        prediction = model(train_feature)
        loss = mae_loss(prediction, train_target.float().unsqueeze(1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_list += [loss.item()]
        print(f"iteration [{i + 1}/{sample_num}] Loss = {loss.item():.3f}")

    plt.plot(range(sample_num), loss_list, marker='o', label='Validation')
    plt.xlabel('iterations')
    plt.ylabel('MAE loss')
    plt.title('Loss vs Iteration')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('Debugger_Loss_Iter.png')
    plt.close()

    comparison(model, sample_num)


# Evaluate the trained model by plugging in each x coord and see the generated comparative graph
def comparison(model: ANN, sample_num: int) -> None:
    model.eval()
    prediction_list = []
    for i in range(sample_num):
        train_feature = tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, i / sample_num], dtype=float32)
        prediction = model(train_feature)
        prediction_list += [prediction.item()]

    target_list = generate_targets(sample_num)
    x_list = [(i - sample_num / 2) / sample_num for i in list(range(sample_num))]

    plt.plot(x_list, target_list, marker='o', label='Target')
    plt.plot(x_list, prediction_list, marker='o', label='Prediction')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('Prediction-target Comparison')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.savefig('Debugger_Comparison.png')
    plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_train()

After executing, the output is something like the attached image. (On the image, the scale of the x label is wrong, but it should not be part of the learning issue)
The current problematic output image of my program. The exact shape of the line may vary, but nothing close to the target.
Image of loss over iterations
The correct output that I am expecting is a shape close to the target, similar to the attached image.
A correct output image, from a single-time success for unknown reason which I failed to recreate
I notice that usually tensor mismatch is a common reason for not learning, and I have deliberately checked the shapes and dtypes of the incoming and outputting tensors. Unfortunately, I found those tensors align with my expectations.
train:
train_feature: (10,6)     float32
train_target.shape([10,1])     float32
prediction: ([10,1])      float32

comparison:
train_feature:([10,6])       float32
prediction([10,1])      float32


The training is fine, but the comparison code is wrong though: You are sampling x uniformly in range(0,1). Try to correct it and train again.
    for i in range(sample_num):
        train_feature = tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, i / sample_num], dtype=float32)

